# Modificar String

Tags: java

Quisiera darle formato a un `string` en *Java*.

Ejemplo, tomar el siguiente `string`

```
hola munDO.
```

Y que quede así:

```
Hola Mundo.
```

La primer letra de cada palabra este en mayúscula.

Comment: Me sorprende que con tu historial de preguntas no hayas realizado esta tan básica, sin un ejemplo básico de lo que has intentado. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Puedes usar [WordUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html), la librería de apache. Ejemplo: `WordUtils.capitalize(str);`  o bien `WordUtils.capitalizeFully("holamunDO");`

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) que viene en la librería Apache Commons

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("hola munDO")
```

Y obtendrás

> Hola Mundo

O si no deseas usar una librería externa, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
    String source = "hola munDO";
    StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

    String[] strArr = source.split(" ");
    for (String str : strArr) {
        char[] stringArray = str.trim().toCharArray();
        stringArray[0] = Character.toUpperCase(stringArray[0]);
        str = new String(stringArray);

        res.append(str).append(" ");
    }

    System.out.print("Resultado: " + res.toString().trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

usa el método [toLowerCase()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_tolowercase.htm) para convertir a minusculas, separa las palabras usando split(), al tener el array con las palabras puedes convertir la primera letra a mayuscula mediante `Character.toUpperCase()`

```
String s = "hola munDO";
String[] palabras  = s.toLowerCase().split(" ");
String resultado = "";
Log.i(TAG, "palabras : " + palabras.length );
for (int i = 0; i< palabras.length ; i ++) {
    resultado +=  Character.toUpperCase(palabras[i].charAt(0)) + palabras[i].substring(1) + " ";
}
System.out.println(resultado);
```

para obtener

```
Hola Mundo
```